# How to convert asynchronous set FlipFlop Hard macro into asynchronous reset FlipFlop?

Tags: flipflop

My query is, if there is a asynchronous set flop in a library but the implementation or RTL required a asynchronous reset flop, how to achieve this?

Comment: What language are you using? What platform are you targeting for implementation?

Comment: Add couple of inverters?

Answer (score 0):

If you have an asynchronous set flip flop (with inputs D,S, clock C, and output Q), you can make a an asynchronous reset flip flop simply by inverting D and Q.

`async_set_FF_S := async_clear_FF_R;
async_set_FF_D := not async_clear_FF_D;
asunc_set_FF_Clk := async_clear_FF_clk;
async_clear_FF_Q := not async_set_FF_Q;`

you may need to take care with global resets (which are now global sets).
I'm surprised your synthesis tools don't have an asynchronous clear flipflop, what is it?

Comment: Basically its an interview question.